# How to create a web project for existing source code

Tags: asp.net

I have a source file and I want to create the project for it in VS2010. I have the option in VS2010 to create project from source code but it is not creating a web project.

Can you help me please how can I create a web project?

Thanks,
Alina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a VS project, then copy-paste files from disk into VS (right-click on project > paste).